# M3U8 file is not playable

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, http-live-streaming, video.js, m3u8

The M3U8 file looks like this...

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=https://video.lk.databoxtech.com/key/WWWME0DL40P5YAZE
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10.023222,
https://cdn.video.lk.databoxtech.com/segments/WWWME0DL40P5YAZE/chunk0.ts
#EXTINF:10.000000,
https://cdn.video.lk.databoxtech.com/segments/WWWME0DL40P5YAZE/chunk1.ts
...
```

The URL to key is giving a 403 error but after changing the referer header I was abled to get this as the response.

```
32XORKNFRMD9Y/74QRtQ6Q==
```

I also tried to download this using ffmpeg but it returned the following error.

```
[hls @ 0x557a543f4a00] Error when loading first segment 'https://cdn.video.lk.databoxtech.com/segments/WWWME0DL40P5YAZE/chunk0.ts'
playlist.m3u8: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The site that the video is hosted is using video.js for video rendering. Can anyone figure out how can I download this in a playable format ?

Answer (score 2):

Since the `EXT-X-KEY` entry doesn't specify a `KEYFORMAT` the assumed format is binary (16-bytes for AES-128).

The key response is a base64 encoded string. If you want to use that key convert it to binary and override the `URI` in `EXT-X-KEY`, then `ffmpeg` will decode it just fine.

Do not infringe the copyright.

Comment: Tnkz but I have some troubles getting this to work. The binary decode of the b64 looks something like "�e�D�ED��c��A�". So should I just copy and paste this directly into the file? I tried this as "#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,�e�D�ED��c��A�" but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Also this is not a copyright infringement. I just wanna download my class videos so I can watch them offline :)

Comment: @Geemo Use a command line tool to decode the Base64 directly to a file, update the key URIs in the `m3u8` playlist. Repeat for each new key using a different file. Or decrypt the segments manually with `openssl` and make a new playlist with them (without the `EXT-X-KEY`)